# Timing traps in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script background process that runs "nohupped". This process shall receive signals in a trap, but when playing around with some code, I noticed that some signals are ignored if the interval between them is too small. The execution of the trap function takes too much time and therefore the subsequent signal goes
unserved. Unfortunately, the trap command doesn't have some kind of signal queue, that's why I am asking: What is the best way to solve this problem?

A simple example:

```
function  receive_signal()
{
local TIMESTAMP=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`
echo "some text" > $TIMESTAMP
}

trap receive_signal USR1

while :
do 
   sleep 5
done
```

Comment: When I had a class in shell programming, the instructor was very big on nesting trap statements. I recall that he was trying to protect against this very issue. I can't say I've seen this turn up in the general shell programming literature, AND I don't use traps often enough to include an example, but it might be worth a quick search. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest change, without redesigning your approach, is to use [realtime signals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/realtime.html), which queue.

This is not portable.  Realtime signals themselves are an optional extension, and shell and utility support for them are not required by the extension in any case.  However, it so happens that the relevant GNU utilities on Linux — `bash(1)` and `kill(1)` — *do* support realtime signals in a commonsense way.  So, you can say:

```
trap sahandler RTMIN+1
```

and, elsewhere:

```
$ kill RTMIN+1 $pid_of_my_process
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider multiple one line trap statements?  One for each signal you want to block or process?

```
trap dosomething 15
trap segfault    SEGV
```

Also you want to have the least possible code in a signal handler for the reason you just encountered.

Edit - for bash you can code your own error handling / signal handling in C, or anything else using modern signal semantics if you want with dynamically loadable modules:

http://cfajohnson.com/shell/articles/dynamically-loadable/

Comment: My problem is that standard signals are not reliable. However, I read here http://www.visolve.com/squidrtsignal.php#Using_RealTime_signals_for_network_IO something about real-time signals. Can they be used in shell script like standard signals?

Comment: That is correct - when you receive a bunch of signals all at once, some may get lost. I do not know how shells actually handle signals under the covers.  You can directly modify bash - see the edit in the answer above